# Burn stain on unknown countertop material

Tags: kitchens

[image: Inside the cabinet][image: Underside of the overhang][image: top-down picture of the edge of the countertop][image]

Yesterday morning I placed a burning hot stainless steel frying pan on the countertop in the house I live in. I got distracted by other things and I am pretty sure it stayed there for a while. Upon removal, I discovered a perfectly circular heat stain on the countertop. I don't know what material the countertop is made out of. I included pictures of the stain and the area around it, as well as the edge of the countertop.

Today, I tried scrubbing it with baking soda and water for about 20 minutes but I didn't see any difference.

Any idea on what kind of material this countertop is made out of and/or any ways to remove the stain would be really helpful.

The owner mentioned it's not quartz, granite or marble but didn't say what it was.It looks like it's a plastic cover on wooden material.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: countertop & stain]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. More information, and possibly a picture of the edge of the counter, would help us help you.

Comment: If you add the URL of the picture, someone will be along to edit it into your post. And, just about anything else you can think of.

Comment: Can we have a picture of the edge looking at it edge-on, instead of top-down?

Comment: Can you also get a (well-lit) picture from the underside of the overhang? And maybe one of the underside from inside a cabinet? Those may help determine what the counter is made of.

Comment: I have added two more pictures that are hopefully helpful

Comment: @mmathis I have added the pictures you requested. Please let me know if that helps!

Comment: @DanielGriscom I have added a picture of the edge.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have added a top-down picture of the edge.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a laminate such as Formica, which cannot be repaired from heat damage. Your only option really is to replace the affected portion, either with another piece of Formica or with some kind of insert like a cutting board, trivet, etc.

You might also be able to put a new layer of laminate over top.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r27oBVmLTN4) from This Old House shows some methods for replacing the affected portion.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Corian, or some composite material like it. Some (like Corian) can be repaired.
https://www.thriftyfun.com/tf84004479.tip.html